# The datasnapshot key is appearing as value data becomes null

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When I try to get data snapshots from firebase. I don't get data properly. The key is actually in value.

```
   DatabaseReference mmmmref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("MessageRooms")
                                    .child(id).child("messages");
mmmmref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

Override
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

     String ms =  dataSnapshot.getValue(message.class).getText();
}
```

so I get null.

My DataSnapshot appears like this in logd

```
{ key = messages, 
value = {-LeNVOFh_Bo6g7Z69Ibq=
           {text=zzzz, date=19-05-08 22:33:09, type=text}
         } 
}
```

The key here should have been this **LeNVOFh_Bo6g7Z69Ibq**  instead of **messages**

I need an answer that can work for a list of messages.
Code for insertion in db

```
String RoomKey = mref.child("MessageRooms").push().getKey();
chatroomref =  mref.child("MessageRooms").child(RoomKey);
chatroomref.child("creator").setValue(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid());
chatroomref.child("member").setValue(userids);
roommesssageRef = chatroomref.child("messages");

message message = new message();
message.setDate(Mfirebase.getTimeStamp());
message.setText("zzzz");
message.setType("text");

roommesssageRef.push().setValue(message);
```

Message model class

```
public class message {

    String text;
    String type;
    String date;

    public message() {
    }

    public message(String text, String type, String date) {
        this.text = text;
        this.type = type;
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

Database

[image]

Comment: can you post your message.class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `message.class` has the types matching your types in the Firebase database, the only problem you have is the reference.

You need to go one level deeper

```
DatabaseReference    ref = chatroomref.child("messages").child("-LeNVOFh_Bo6g7Z69lbq");
```

If you are looping with `getChildren()` please check your message.class to match the same name and variable types as you have in Firebase.

Comment: I updated the question. In the given picture there is only one message what if there are many messages how will I know the key?

Comment: In that case you run the query/listener one level higher, but loop over the results in `onDataChange`. So `for (DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) { child.getValue(message.class).getText() }`.

Comment: @RohaitasTanoli , exactly as Frank says

Comment: I didn't use for loop that was the problem. now it has been resolved thanks..!